# SSH connection refused on windows ssh server

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to turn my laptop (windows 11) into a SSH server which I can connect to, but for some reason it's refusing the connection; here's what I did:

-Installed the ssh server and client on the laptop and started the service (it sets a firewall inbound rule for TCP/UDP on port 22)
-made a new user called sshuser (with password) 
-set up portforwarding (my laptop is connected via wifi) here's the config for that:
name: SSH
Protocol: TCP/UDP
IP address Remote host: "my public ip address" ~ "my public ip address" (it takes a range)
Host LAN: The IPv4 for Wireless LAN adapter WiFi
WAN port: 22~22 (also takes a range)
Host port LAN: 22

I then tried to connect from a machine that runs on Arch Linux doing `ssh sshuser@mypublicipaddress -p 22` but got hit with 'Connection refused', and I'm unsure what's causing this

you can find a capture of the forwarding rule
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PekGS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> -set up portforwarding (my laptop is connected via wifi) here's the config for that: name: SSH Protocol: TCP/UDP IP address Remote host:
> "my public ip address" ~ "my public ip address" (it takes a range)
> Host LAN: The IPv4 for Wireless LAN adapter WiFi WAN port: 22~22 (also
> takes a range) Host port LAN: 22

This looks wrong to me. Most routers do not have you specify "my public ipaddress" as part of the forward rule - Looks like an option to whitelist incoming IP address instead - Can you make a screen capture on the forwarding rule

Another thing is that lots of routers/ISP disallow connection on its port 22. Try to expose 2222 on your router instead

Step by step things that you can do to narrow down the issue

- Check on the SSH Server if port 22 is listening
- Check if you can SSH to the server from local network first, using server's private IP
- `ssh -v` for more information

Comment: Server is listening on port 22,
I connected to the server from the server itself and it works fine
Also I added a capture of the forwarding route in my original post but  it's in italian

Comment: I finally found the documentation given by the ISP and you were right, the range of IPs is just a whitelist feature